# Setting an \abnormalparskip with memoir and babel french

Tags: spacing, memoir, babel, parskip

I'm experiencing an issue trying to set a non-zero `\abnormalparskip` using the `memoir` class with chapterstyle `ell` and the `french` (or `francais`, or `frenchb`) `babel` package.

Doing so moves chapter titles and numbers down : without babel (or without `abnormalpageskip`, this gets rendered :

[image: Without babel]

and with babel and the `abnormalparskip` setting, I get this :

[image: With babel french]

Here is a minimal working example :

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\chapterstyle{ell}
\abnormalparskip{4mm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample chapter}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not able to reproduce the issue; can you tell what TeX distribution you're using?

Comment: I was using Texlive 2014 on Windows, but upgrading everything to the latest version solved my issue. Thanks !

Comment: So I'll vote for closing; but as the question was upvoted, it won't disappear and it may still help future readers. Glad to know you're on track again! `:-)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue has been solved by a software update